# How to retrieve information of a user in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, user-interface, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a site where it requires me to pull info from the registration that a user does like their gender and their name. I am using a real-time database and am trying to pull info from the 'users' section of the database.

My code for adding the user into the real-time database.

```
 const email = txtEmail.value;
 const password = txtPassword.value;
 const name =  txtName.value;
 const gender = txtGender.value
 const industry = txtIndustry.value;

  database.ref('users/' + name).set({
    Email: email,
    Password: password,
    Gender: gender,
    Industry: industry
  });
```

I want to create something where when the user logs in or register that I am able to pull their registration credentials and have something simple happen like "Welcome Bob" by taking the name bob from the realtime database.

Answer (score 1):

```
database.ref('users/' + name).once('value', function(data) {
  // do something with the data
});
```